# Modifying Circuit Arrows, Boxes and Generic Component

Tags: circuitikz

I need this

[image]

and this is my code so far:

[image]

```
  \begin{center}
  \shorthandoff{:!}
  \begin{figure}[H]     % Montage pour essai à vide
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}         {scale=1} % scaling factor du schéma
     \begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
        \draw
        %%-----V in-----%% 
        (0, 0) to [sV,l={V$_g$}] (0,4)
        to [short] ++(3,0) coordinate (1)
        to [short, i_={I$_{m}$}] ++(0,-1) coordinate (2)
        to [short] ++(-.5,0) 
        to [short, i_={I$_{fe}$}] ++(0,-.5) 
        to [R,l={R$_{fe}$}] ++(0,-2)
        to [short] ++(+.5,0) coordinate (3)
        to [short] ++(0,-.5) coordinate (4)
        to [short] (0,0)

        %-----------
        (2) to [short] ++(+.5,0) 
        to [short, i={I$_{\psi}$}] ++(0,-.5) 
        to [L,l={X$_{\psi}$}] ++(0,-2)
        to [short] (3)

       %-------------
       (1) to [short, i={I$_{2}$}] ++(2,0) 
        to [R,l={R$_{eq}$}] ++(2,0)
        to [L,l={X$_{eq}$}] ++(2,0)
        node[transformer, anchor=A1,yscale=1.9] (T) {}
        (T.A2)  to [short] (4)

        (T.B1)   to [short] ++(1,0)
        to [generic] ++(0,-4)
        to [short] (T.B2)
                ;
        \end{circuitikz}  
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Montage pour essai à vide} \label{MontageEssaiVide}
    \end{figure}
  \shorthandon{:!}
  \end{center}
```

I have played a bit with the american / european current and voltage arrow, but can't make it work with my circuit.

So I would like to knw how to make Curved arrows with label in the middle ?

How can I add $Z_c$ insde the generic component ?

How to box the Outside of the transformer ?

And finally, can I have multiple type of arrows in the same drawing, it look like if I change the european / american arrows, it change for all of them.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Curved arrows:* Use `\draw[->] (node1) edge [bend X=Y] (node2);` where X can be `left` or `right` and Y gives the degree of bending. With the tikz library `arrows` you get a variety of arrows. By adding the option `>=stealth'` you get a particular type of arrow, `shorten >=3pt` tells to stop in a distance of 3pt before the destination.

*Label inside the generic component:* I add `\hspace{-3.5cm}` to the normal label that would otherwise be outside. Just a hack, but I found no other solution.

*Box around transformer:* `\draw[dashed] (T) +(-1,-4.2) rectangle +(1,0.2);` draws a dashed rectangle relative to node (T). Note that the single `+` does not change the position, hence the opposing corners of the rectangle are (T)+(-1,-4.2) and (T)+(1,0.2).

*Multiple types of arrows:* I'm not completely sure what you mean. You now have already two types of arrows. Maybe ask another question with a more precise description.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
\draw
%%-----V in-----%% 
(0, 0) to [sV,l={V$_g$}] (0,4)
to [short,-o] ++(1,0) coordinate (a) %%% NEW
to [short] ++(2,0) coordinate (1)    %%% CHANGED
to [short, i_={I$_{m}$}] ++(0,-1) coordinate (2)
to [short] ++(-.5,0) 
to [short, i_={I$_{fe}$}] ++(0,-.5) 
to [R,l={R$_{fe}$}] ++(0,-2)
to [short] ++(+.5,0) coordinate (3)
to [short] ++(0,-.5) coordinate (4)
to [short,-o] (1,0) coordinate (b)   %%% NEW
to [short] (0,0)

%-----------
(2) to [short] ++(+.5,0) 
to [short, i={I$_{\psi}$}] ++(0,-.5) 
to [L,l={X$_{\psi}$}] ++(0,-2)
to [short] (3)

%-------------
(1) to [short, i={I$_{2}$}] ++(2,0) 
to [R,l={R$_{eq}$}] ++(2,0)
to [L,l={X$_{eq}$}] ++(2,0)
node[transformer, anchor=A1,yscale=1.9] (T) {}
(T.A2)  to [short] (4)

(T.B1)
to [short,-o] ++(1,0) coordinate (c) %%% NEW
to [short] ++(1,0)
to [generic,l={\hspace{-3.5ex}$\mathrm{Z}_c$}] ++(0,-4)) %%% CHANGED
to [short,-o] ++(-1,0) coordinate (d)%%% NEW
to [short] (T.B2)
;
%%% NEW NEW NEW
\path (a) -- node[xshift=3ex] (Eg) {$\mathrm{E}_g$} (b);
\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=3pt]
   (Eg) edge[bend right=10] (a)
        edge[bend left=10]  (b);
\path (c) -- node[xshift=-3ex] (Ec) {$\mathrm{E}_c$} (d);
\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=3pt]
   (Ec) edge[bend left=10]  (c)
        edge[bend right=10] (d);
\draw[dashed] (T) +(-1,-4.2) rectangle +(1,0.2);
\end{circuitikz}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** To magnify components, use the `/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length` option, like that:

```
node[transformer, anchor=A1,yscale=1.9,/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2.5cm] (T) {}
[L,l={X$_{eq}$},/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=2.5cm]
```

In the `circuitikz` components you can shorten the key to `bipoles/length`, in the `tikz` elements to `circuitikz/bipoles/length`, resulting in

```
node[transformer, anchor=A1,yscale=1.9,circuitikz/bipoles/length=2.5cm] (T) {}
[L,l={X$_{eq}$},bipoles/length=2.5cm]
```

Comment: Woaw, that's a lot of information. Thank you for answering all this.

Comment: Do you by any chance know a way to stretch the look of the inductor (&Transformer) ?

Comment: @SebastienComtois I've added a note on how to magnify components.